# Using chars into an int datatype

Tags: c, arrays, types, int

Using C, One array with 5 memory spaces

```
int call[5]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use the first 3 spaces of the array to make a base-36 conversion (meaning 1K0 base-36 equals to 2040 in base-10), the other 2 spaces would be filled with data (probably more ints).

However... does **1K0** look actually like an int? (to me K looks like a char and in theory, char should be enough -127 to 127 for the conversion using base-36)

however what would happen if i try to do this using int instead of char?

is there any alternative to use a base-36 conversion in the first array only mixed with ints for the rest of the spaces in memory

does it matter? (since the array was declared int)

EDIT: to be clear i just want to know if i can declare an int array and fill it with chars, and if i cant, how can i achieve this?

Comment: I would like to have some extra detail on why are you battling with base 36 for starters and where do you need it and if you need to do math on it or just store it.

Comment: Yes, you can declare an `int` array and fill it with chars.

Comment: @Arheisel Basically i need to store a huge amount of information and im limited by memory, so im looking for alternatives to reduce the numbers, int8 is not enough, so the first it came to my mind is to use a non standar higher base conversion

Comment: @GoatZero you will not save any space at all trying to use another base. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if you can tell the compiler that, you can signal Hex (0x), octal (o) Binary (b) but base 36 is odd enough to not be standard.

You can always make a function (and maybe embed it in a class) that does the string-to-base10 conversion of base 36

I'll do my best in C terms

```
int base10Number = 0
int base36StringLenght = strlen(base35String);
for( int i = base36StringLenght - 1; i <= 0; i--){ //count from the end of the string back
  char c = base36String[i];
  if(c <= '9'){
    c -= '0' //gives a 0 to 9 range
  }
  else{ //assuming that the string is perfect and has no extra characters is safe to just do this
    c = tolower(c); //first make sure it's lowercase
    c -= 'a' + 10 // this will make the letters start at 10 dec
  }
  base10Number += c * pow(36, base36StringLenght - 1 - i) // the power function specifies which 'wheel' you're turning (imagine an old analog odometer) and then turns the wheel c times, then adds it to the overall sum.
}
```

This whole code works by the theory that every digit starting from the last is worth its base 10 number multipled by 36 to the power of its position from last.
So last digit is c * 36^0 which is one, the c*36^1 and so on. similar on how 2*10^1 equals 20 if the 2 is in second-to-last position.

Hope that some of this makes sense to you, and dont forget to make your base36 number a string

**EDIT:**
  I saw your edit to the answer and the short asnwer is yes, you can totally do that, it would be a waste of space since you'll have a whole 3 bytes unused at all times, you can simply make a char array. Besides, all string functions will demand you to feed them a char array (you can cast it) but if you're storing one digit per array space char will do the trick. If your array is dynamic and/or you need to make some math on it the base 36 to base 10 conversion will allow you to do math and to blow the whole array for a single int or float type. But if you're just going to store it to display it later or to feed it to another function in the same format the conversion is not necessary at all. (If you're working with a big ammount of this numbers and you need to put them in a database converting to base10 and storing in a single in will save tons of space)

PS: also edited the code to use ' ' enclosed chars instead of ascii numbers, thanks for the request!

Comment: Why use numerical ASCII codes instead of `'`-enclosed symbols?

Comment: No particular reason, my bad, I'm just accustomed to it

Comment: Im amazed of how fast you answered,  allow me to put it on my own words in order to understand: so basically you propose to convert it to base-36, make a string, and plug each character of the string into the first 3 values of the array, then when needed, pull out the first 3 values and convert them back to base-10?

Comment: btw, i compiled the code, in order to fix several typos and make it run, and edited your answer so it could run, however instead of getting 1k0 as a result from the input 2040 i get, 93456 which is right (in its decimal form at least) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2040_36 , however i was expecting it to output 1K0 (im not sure what base is this now) see     http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-o-base-36-conversion.html

Comment: heres the code running on an online editor https://onlinegdb.com/rk-TDoK_f

Comment: @GoatZero hey man, sorry I phased out, do you still need my help? The function I made only converts base 36 strings into base 10 numbers, I think I misread your question